# Determinar el número de elementos entre el primer y último elemento cero de la matriz

Tags: c++

Determinar el número de elementos entre el primer y último elemento cero, es decir entre el primer cero y el último cero en la matriz con memoria dinámica. 
El siguiente código corre sin error, pero el resultado no es correcto.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r,c, i, j, count=0;
    cout<<"\n Input number of rows: "; cin>>r;
    cout<<" Input number of columns: "; cin>>c;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int **m = new int* [r];
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[c];  }

    for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[c];
        for (j=0; j<c; j++)  {
            m[i][j] = rand()%200-100; cout<<m[i][j]<<"\t";  }
        cout<<endl;  }
    cout<<endl;

    for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<c; j++)  {
            if (m[i][j]==0)
                break;
            else
                count++; 
        if (j!=c)
            break;   }  }

    if (i!=r && j!=c) {
        for (i=r-1; i>=0; i--)  {
            for (j=c-1; j>=0; j--)  {
                if (m[i][j]==0)
                    break;
                else
                    count++;  
            if (j!=c)
                break;    }   }  }

    cout<<"\n Total of elements between the first and last zero element: " <<r*c-count<<endl;

    delete []m; 

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Hola Nas_04, ¿a que te refieres con elemento cero de la matriz?

Comment: que un elemento de la matriz sea cero, es decir si en la primera fila hay un cero y en el ultima fila hay otro, contar la cantidad de elementos entre el primer cero y el ultimo cero

Comment: Sin incluir los 0? Y que pasa si hay uno o ningun 0? Puedes detallar todo esto en tu pregunta?

Comment: Pero que es lo que quieres hacer en esos casos. Explícanos tu requerimiento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como menciona eferion, hay errores en el algoritmo de búsqueda

Puedes usar este código para encontrar ambos ceros en el array bidimensional

Si encuentras un 0, hay que ver si corresponde al primero o al segundo para asignar las variables i1 y j1 o i2 y j2 según corresponda, sin embargo si es el primer caso hay que continuar para seguir buscando el segundo. Si se encuentra el segundo 0 podemos salir de ambos `for` usando un `goto` y un `label`

```
// Encontrar 
int i1 = -1;
int j1 = -1;
int i2 = -1;
int j2 = -1;
bool foundTwoZeros = false;

for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
        if (m[i][j] == 0)
            if (i1 == -1 && j1 == -1)
            {
                i1 = i;
                j1 = j;
            }
            else
            {
                i2 = i;
                j2 = j;
                foundTwoZeros = true;
                goto foundTwoZeros;
            }
    }
}

foundTwoZeros:
```

Finalmente para calcular cuantos elementos hay entre ambos ceros, hacemos una simple transformación matemática.

Si el arreglo bidimensional lo convertimos a un arreglo unidimensional, la nueva posición en el arreglo está dada por al sgte expresión

```
pos = numElementosXFila * i + j // pseudocódigo
```

En tu caso sería:

```
int pos1 = c * i1 + j1;
int pos2 = c * i2 + j2;
```

Luego nos basta con una simple resta para calcular la distancia entre estas dos posiciones lo cual nos da uno mas que el número de posiciones entre ambas.

```
count = pos2 - pos1 - 1;
```

Te dejo el código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r, c, i, j, count = 0;
    cout << "\n Input number of rows: "; cin >> r;
    cout << " Input number of columns: "; cin >> c;
    srand(time(NULL));


    int **m = new int*[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[c];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        m[i] = new int[c];
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            m[i][j] = rand() % 200 - 100;
            cout << m[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Encontrar los ceros
    int i1 = -1;
    int j1 = -1;
    int i2 = -1;
    int j2 = -1;
    bool foundTwoZeros = false;

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            if (m[i][j] == 0)
                if (i1 == -1 && j1 == -1)
                {
                    i1 = i;
                    j1 = j;
                }
                else
                {
                    i2 = i;
                    j2 = j;
                    foundTwoZeros = true;
                    goto foundTwoZeros;
                }
        }
    }

foundTwoZeros:

    if (foundTwoZeros)
    {
        int pos1 = c * i1 + j1;  // pos1 es la posicion del primer 0
                                 // en un array unidimensional
        int pos2 = c * i2 + j2;  // pos2 es la posición del segundo 0
                                 // en un array unidimenisonal
        count = pos2 - pos1 - 1; // la distancia de ambos puntos - 1
                                 // te dará cuantos elementos hay entre estos

        cout << "\n Total of elements between the first and last zero element: " << count << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n There are no two zero elements";
    }

    delete []m;

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Al correrlo es correcto cuando no hay ceros, pero cuando hay ceros no es correcta la respuesta y la respuesta sale negativa.

Comment: Con que valores lo estas probando y cual es el resultado que obtienes y el esperado? Ten en cuenta que los números son random, podrías probar con data estática?

Comment: Cambié  <<rand()%100-0>> e introduzco los valores de tamaño de 10x10. Ya que con <<rand()%200-100>> no salían ceros.

Comment: Y que resultado obtienes? Por favor ayudame a ayudarte, a mi me corre perfectamente. No puedo estar todo el tiempo resolviendote el problema sino pones esfuerzo de tu parte.

Answer (score 0):

Como primer consejo te recomendaría no usar `conio.h`. Es una librería no estándar y de dudosa utilidad en desarrollos reales.

Por otro lado, cuando haces `delete []m;` has de ser consciente de que no estás borrando nada más que `m`, las reservas de tamaño `c` se están quedando en el limbo. La norma general es que por cada `new` has de incluir un `delete` y en tu código hay dos `new` y un único `delete`.

A mi modo de ver (y esta es una opinión totalmente personal) la forma en la que tabulas el código complica bastante su lectura. Que las llaves de cierre las agrupes al final de la línea te obliga, por ejemplo, a tener que contar cuántas hay para saber cual es la siguiente instrucción a ejecutar... el hecho de concatenar sin venir a cuento varias instrucciones en la misma línea tampoco ayuda a que el código sea legible.

En cuanto a las variables, no necesitas reutilizarlas todo el programa. Puedes crear las variables dentro de los bucles. La ventaja de hacerlo así es que reduces el ámbito de la variable y mejoras la lectura del programa (si una variable deja de existir deja de ser un problema).

Las recomendaciones son eso, recomendaciones, no son de obligado cumplimiento pero nunca están de más y te pueden ayudar a cometer menos errores en el futuro.

Un detalle que me chirría especialmente es eso de calcular la distancia de dos elementos de una matriz. Tu has dicho *array*, luego me temo que no tienes que crear una matriz sino un vector de elementos. Si mis sospechas son ciertas el algoritmo se te va a simplificar muchísimo. Si, en cambio, resulta que tienes que crear una matriz no me termina de quedar claro por qué entiendes que la distancia entre dos elementos pasa por linealizar la matriz como si fuese un vector.

Bueno, vamos a revisar el primer bucle de tu algoritmo de búsqueda:

```
for (int i=0; i<r; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<c; j++)  {
    if (m[i][j]==0)
      break;
    else
      count++; 
    if (j!=c)
      break;
  }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que `break` únicamente abandona un bucle y tu tienes dos anidados. Al llegar a `break`, la ejecución abandonará el bucle `j` y seguirá ejecutando el bucle `i`, por lo que acabará entrando de nuevo en el bucle `j`. En el segundo bucle te pasa exactamente lo mismo.

Si la idea es buscar dos posiciones dentro de un vector (y tu estás tratando la matriz como un vector) prefería gestionar directamente un vector.

```
// Un único new implica un único delete
int* vector = new int[filas*columnas];
```

Por último, la búsqueda del primer y el último elemento de características X se podría encapsular en una función, evitando duplicar el código. Para hacer esta parte hay varias opciones, aunque quizás la más sencilla sea una función que devuelva la siguiente posición de un valor dada una posición inicial y -1 si no hay más valores. Entonces pides el primer valor y después pides el segundo en bucle hasta que la función te devuelve -1, el valor que te dió la vez anterior (y que has de memorizar) es la posición del último '0' de la lista. Algo con una firma tal que:

```
// valor es el número a buscar
// ptr el inicio del vector
// inicio es el índice por donde empieza a buscar
// final indica el índice donde debe finalizar la búsqueda (final del array)
int Posicion(int valor, int* ptr, int inicio, int final);
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no tengo no tengo que hacerlo con funciones, sino en la funcion principal.

Comment: Lo de la función era en plan sugerencia. Se puede hacer perfectamente sin funciones.